# conditional DI with the help of config file

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

How can we achieve conditional Dependency Injection with the help of Unity Application block config file ? Below is my piece of code.

```
namespace DependencyInjection
{
   //UI
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer objContainer = new UnityContainer();
        objContainer.LoadConfiguration();  //loads from app

        Customer obj = objContainer.Resolve<Customer>();

        obj.CustomerName = "test1";
        obj.Add();
    }
}

//ML
public class Customer
{

    private IDAL Odal;
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Customer(IDAL iobj)
    {
        Odal = iobj;
    }
    public void Add()
    {

        Odal.Add();
    }
}

//DAL

public interface IDAL
{
    void Add();
}

public class SQLServerDAL:IDAL
{
    public void Add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SQL Server inserted");
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }
}

public class OracleDAL:IDAL
{
    public void Add()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oracle inserted");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

And my config file is like below:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">    
<container>
<register type="DependencyInjection.IDAL, DependencyInjection"
mapTo="DependencyInjection.SQLServerDAL,DependencyInjection"/>
</container>
</unity>
```

How can I achieve the following :

```
If(somecondition=true)
  Customer object should resolve to SQLServerDal
Else
  Customer object should resolve to OracleDal
```

Is it possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Where does `somecondition` come from? a configuration file? Or a runtime value?

Comment: how does that matter ? Suppose it is a runtime value..then what is the solution ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853(v=pandp.20).aspx